# Incremental addition of 3d matrix with respect to time. Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I have a variable `h.data` which generates a dynamic 128x14 matrix, I can controls its out put by using `pause(n)` function

**example:**

This example plots an the `new_data` variable every `0.5` seconds.

```
h = EmotivEEG
h.Run

for i = 1:10
   new_data = h.data;
   plot(new_data);
   pause(0.5)
end

h.delete;
```

so what I wanted to do was on every `0.5` seconds the old data should go back and new data should be in the front (making a 3d cat matrix on every `0.5` iterations)

**example:**

```
new_data(:,:,1) =  % present iteration
     128x14

new_data(:,:,2) = % past 1 iteration
     128x14
       |
       |
       |
new_data(:,:,m) = % past m iterations
     128x14
```

Could anyone tell me how I could do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `newdata(:,:,i)=h.data` as you have in your example?

Comment: @David there is nothing wrong with it, I just want an output to be like that instead of plotting.

Comment: David is rigth, if you take that line of code you already have it. You may want to do `newdata(:,:,end+1)` maybe?

Comment: so if i remove the `plot(new_data)` and put `new_data(:,:,i+1)` would that do?

Comment: No I think `new_data(:,:,i)` is fine, and yes, just plot the same thing.